# Cypress visit and wait timeouts ignored

Tags: timeout, e2e-testing, cypress

I created a test where I setup a route, try to visit a page which makes an API request to the route and then wait for the route response:

```
cy
    .server()
    .route('GET', '/api/testing')
    .as('testing');
cy.visit('/index.html', { timeout: 60000 });
cy.wait('@testing', { timeout: 60000 });
```

This only waits for the Cypress global default `responseTimeout` of 30 seconds and then fails the API request.

Here's the error message logged by Cypress in the console:

> Cypress errored attempting to make an http request to this url:
>   https://localhost:4200/api/testing
>
> The error was:
>
> ESOCKETTIMEDOUT
>
> The stack trace was:
>
> Error: ESOCKETTIMEDOUT
>       at ClientRequest. (…\node_modules\cypress\dist\Cypress\resources\app\packages\server\node_modules\request\request.js:778:19)
>       at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:314:30)
>       at emitNone (events.js:105:13)
>       at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:207:7)
>       at TLSSocket.emitTimeout (_http_client.js:722:34)
>       at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:314:30)
>       at emitNone (events.js:105:13)
>       at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:207:7)
>       at TLSSocket.Socket._onTimeout (net.js:402:8)
>       at ontimeout (timers.js:469:11)
>       at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:304:5)
>       at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:264:5)

Adding a `responseTimeout` to the global config of Cypress will increase the timeout, but why isn't the timeout for either the `visit` or the `wait` occurring?

Comment: I presume you've set a **baseUrl** in cypress.json? since `cy.visit('/index.html')` by itself will probably not navigate to the home page.

Comment: The timeout works ok for me - if I throw in a bogus route(), it waits the full 60s then fails. Clicking the failed command shows `Error:    CypressError: Timed out retrying: cy.wait() timed out waiting 60000ms for the 1st request to the route: 'testing'. No request ever occurred` in the console.

Comment: Correct, a **baseUrl** is being used. Trying a bogus route it also waits for me. But when using a legitimate route and pausing the server response, using a debugger in the server code, it only wait for the `responseTimeout`.

Comment: Cheers, that clarifies some things. I'm wondering how you stop the particular route without stopping the whole app under test (since the route in question looks relative to the app). Sorry if I missed something obvious.

Comment: The server app is .Net Core running inside of Visual Studio. A break point is set in the API controller which is called by JavaScript on the index.html page. So the entire page is served to the browser, JavaScript executes, sends a request back to the API controller on the server, hits the break point and I never continue, so a timeout occurs. Does that help? Thank you for your time thinking about this.

Comment: Indeed, that helps. An interesting problem, testing a resource failure. Will test a little and post if I find anything.

Answer (score 3):

See the code example on this page [commands - wait - Alias](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/wait.html#Alias)

```js
// Wait for the route aliased as 'getAccount' to respond
// without changing or stubbing its response
cy.server()
cy.route('/accounts/*').as('getAccount')
cy.visit('/accounts/123')
cy.wait('@getAccount').then((xhr) => {
  // we can now access the low level xhr
  // that contains the request body,
  // response body, status, etc
})
```

I would add the `then((xhr) =>` to your code and see what response is coming through.

Logic says that if a bogus route waits the full timeout, but a 'failed legitimate route' does not, then a response with failure code is being sent back from the server within the timeout period.

---

The block of code in request.js where the error comes from has an interesting comment.

```js
self.req.on('socket', function(socket) {
  var setReqTimeout = function() {
    // This timeout sets the amount of time to wait *between* bytes sent
    // from the server once connected.
    //
    // In particular, it's useful for erroring if the server fails to send
    // data halfway through streaming a response.
    self.req.setTimeout(timeout, function () {
      if (self.req) {
        self.abort()
        var e = new Error('ESOCKETTIMEDOUT')  <-- LINE 778 REFERENCED IN MESSAGE
        e.code = 'ESOCKETTIMEDOUT'
        e.connect = false
        self.emit('error', e)
      }
    })
  }
```

This may be a condition you want to test for (i.e connection broken mid-response).
Unfortunately, there seems to be no syntax `cy.wait().catch()`, see [Commands-Are-Not-Promises](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/introduction-to-cypress.html#Commands-Are-Not-Promises)

> You cannot add a .catch error handler to a failed command.

You may want to try stubbing the route instead of setting the breakpoint on the server, but I'm not sure what form the fake response should take. (Ref [route with stubbing](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/route.html#With-Stubbing))

Comment: Perhaps a response is being sent back from Visual Studio, this is not clear, capturing the xhr in the promise does not seem to include anything additional that is helpful beyond what Cypress captures and logs itself. What's really weird is changing the global `responseTimeout` does wait.

Comment: Thinking about it further I guess I need to look at it as two separate `responseTimeout`s. The first is on the actual request. It seems there's no way to adjust this timeout, unless you modify the global `responseTimeout`. The second is on `wait`. which only adjusts the time this function will wait before throwing a timeout. So if the `wait` timeout is less than the actual request then the `wait` will throw the error. If it is greater then the actual request throws an error before the timeout of the `wait` is exceeded.

Comment: Yes, that fits with the error message - `Error: ESOCKETTIMEDOUT
at ClientRequest` - means the request part is likely causing the error. However, it's not the expected error as given [here](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/wait.html#Timeouts)

Answer (score 1):

.vist() and .wait() didn't work for me, error logs on cypress suggested using .request() instead which works fine.

```js
cy.server(); 
cy.request('/api/path').then((xhr) => {
  console.log(xhr.body)
})
```